# Password PXE Install

Tags: password, maas, pxe

I tried to install Ubuntu server using PXE.

During the installation the system never ask me for a password or a login but at the end of the installation when the computer restart he asked me for a login and a password but i don't what are the password and the login :-/.

I'm working with MAAS and cobbler.

Comment: have you tried with ubuntu as for both username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using one of the default kcikstart templates in cobbler.  The password for root and/or an initial user is probably defined in there.  In my preseed I don't create an initial user, but I do define root's password.  The lines that do this are:

```
d-i     passwd/root-login       boolean true
d-i     passwd/root-password-crypted password "MD5 Hash"
```

Where "MD5 Hash" is the MD5 hash of your desired password.  You can get a correctly encrypted MD5 string for your password by running:

```
mkpasswd -H md5 "yourpassword"
```